# NodeJs return from external API

Tags: node.js, api, request

I'm trying to get data from this endpoint, and I can see the json response in my console log.

But for whatever reason I can't seem to return data.

```
module.exports.getMenu = async (options) => {return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
request(url+'/menu', (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        reject(error);
    } else if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        reject(new Error(`Network request returned status code ${response.statusCode}`));
    } else {
      console.log(body);
        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
    }
});
```

I'm using request 2.88.0. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Can you show us what are you doing on the other end when you call getMenu()?

Comment: I'm just calling my localhost:port/menu

Comment: Ok but somewhere you ar doing something like const menu = require('../menu') and then myMenu = menu.getMenu()? Can you show us the code on the menu router.

Comment: Thanks you made me realize why... So yeah in my route I tried to return a non existing object...